# groovy binding issue

Tags: binding, groovy

I have sample code as below

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

abstract class MyClass extends Script {

    void testMethod(Integer x) {
        println "x = $x"
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    compilerConfiguration = new CompilerConfiguration();
    compilerConfiguration.setScriptBaseClass("MyClass");
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(new Binding(), compilerConfiguration);
    shell.evaluate("testMethod 1")
}
```

When I run this class it prints `x = 1`
now if I change the `"testMethod 1"` to `"testMethod -1"` it fails with

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: testMethod for class: Script1
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: testMethod for class: Script1
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at Test.run(Test.groovy:15)
```

Now I change `"testMethod -1"` to `"testMethod (-1)"`. It again works and printed `x = -1`

What I need to understand is why Groovy is asking for the parentheses for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because without parentheses, it is assuming you are trying to subtract 1 from a property called `testMethod` (ie: `testMethod - 1`)

You need the parentheses to inform the parser that this is a method call rather than a subtraction operation

---

#### Edit

I came up with a horrible way to get this to work:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

abstract class MyClass extends Script {
  private methods = [:]
  
  class MinusableMethod {
    Script declarer
    Method method
    MinusableMethod( Script d, Method m ) {
      this.declarer = d
      this.method = m
    }
    def minus( amount ) {
      method.invoke( declarer, -amount )
    }
  }

  public MyClass() {
    super()
    methods = MyClass.getDeclaredMethods().grep {
      it.name != 'propertyMissing' && !it.synthetic
    }.collectEntries {
      [ (it.name): new MinusableMethod( this, it ) ]
    } 
  }

  def propertyMissing( String name ) {
    methods[ name ]
  }

  void testMethod(Integer x) {
      println "x = $x"
  }
}

static main( args ) {
  def compilerConfiguration = new CompilerConfiguration();
  compilerConfiguration.setScriptBaseClass( 'MyClass' );
  GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(new Binding(), compilerConfiguration);
  shell.evaluate("testMethod - 1")
}
```

But ***this will probably break under other conditions***

In the long run, getting people to write valid scripts is probably the better route to take...

Comment: Is there anyway I can override this behaviour?

Comment: @Manoj Not really...trying to think of a way, but nothing simple is coming to mind

Comment: @Manoj Came up with a solution, but I don't recommend it (however, it's interesting to try and write) ;-)

Comment: testMethod 0-1 would probably work. Parsing the strings yourself and adding () or "0" MIGHT work if your code doesn't get too complex. Mostly I recommend not twisting a compiler to compile something it wasn't specifically designed to compile--just because Ruby users have taken the fact that ruby will compile slop to make up for the fact that they don't want to code their own interpreter doesn't mean twisted semi-clear DSLs that manage to compile in an existing language are a good thing--I prefer creating a real DSL if one is needed where you have control over ALL the syntax.